# Java package import

Tags: java, import, package

I have the following folder and file structure...

```
Working directory
   ---financial
      ---bank
        Bank.java
      ---person
        Customer.java
   Main.java
```

I have to import *Bank.java* to *Customer.java* with this folder structure. How can I do it?

Comment: `import financial.bank.Bank` ?!

Comment: I can import the Bank into the Main but I have to import it to the Customer.java and it doesn't work with import financial.bank.Bank

Comment: If you already tried it and "it doesn't work", why didn't you tell us? Shall we guess?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is too vague and unclear. Please [edit] the question and show us the error message, how/what you're trying to do (code) and so on. In other words, a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

If you are in the customer.java, then import Bank using,

```
import financial.bank.Bank;

public class Customer {
.....
...
}
```